# What are the odds of making a royal flush after the flop in Texas Hold 'Em?

Tags: texas-hold-em

My sister was playing no limit Texas Hold'Em at a table with six players and after the flop she made a royal flush. Can you tell me the odds on that happening?
They must be astronomical.

Comment: Can your sister buy me a lottery ticket?

Answer (score 9):

There are 2598960 unique 5-card poker hands (C(n,r) = C(52, 5) = 2598960). 4 of those are royal flushes. So, the odds of one specific player flopping a royal flush would be 4-in-2598960, or 1-in-649740.

Comment: Yes.  Although if a pair of 4's are dealt to you, the odds of making a royal flush after the flop is significantly lower :)  If you're dealt two suited cards between 10 and A, then the odds improve to 1-in-19,600.

Comment: If you ask a somewhat vague question, you tend to get the easiest specific answer. :)

Comment: ??  @Chris farmer, for your 4//2.5 million hands, I take it that also does include a RSF that is on the board ONLY, meaning you'd split the pot and wouldn't "win" anything.  If true, then you'd have to eliminate 1/7th of the 1/650k possibilities to beat the others (and assume they don't get their own RSF at the same time and tie).  Correct?  [[ Pokerstars result a few days ago, which is why I care:)  "Hand #193344547027: DaaBoss wins pot (2,646) with a Royal Flush" ]]

Comment: @DaaBoss the question is on flopping the royal flush, not rivering it. So only the first 5 cards matter. Altho i agree with Drfbag, the assumption is you hold 2 of the 5 RF cards.

Comment: @sakon no, there is no assumption made in the question. There is nothing written about hole cards already being dealt. The question simply is if you sit down at a Texas hold'em poker table, what are the odds that you have a royal flush after the hole cards and the flop are dealt. Above is the correct answer to that question.

Comment: @azimut if you say so :)

Answer (score -1):

I would disagree Chris with your probabilities.
There is only possibility of one royal flush occurring in any one round. So it be 1 in 2.6 million of that occurring.
But the odds slightly increase on turn and river.
Unlike 5/7 card stud poker, then it be 1 in 650,000 of it occurring.

Comment: Op specifically asked about flopping a Royal Flush, so the answer provided by Chris is accurate.